# Do the Pali suttas refer to unwholesome gift benefactors?

Tags: dana

I was browsing a new set of Sutta translations by a renowned translator, and happened to read the publisher wrote a special acknowledgement towards a certain charitable foundation that was established by a major corporation for the benefit of children; even though this corporation arguably produces & sell certain products that not only can harm children when consumed in excess but also generates craving in both children & adults. I found it ironic that a charitable foundation established upon financial profits from craving would be the primary sponsor of Sutta translations specifically on the subject of the cessation of craving.

Do any Pali suttas refer to unwholesome gift benefactors; from which proposed charitable gifts should ideally be declined?

Comment: I guess that depends on their intentions. It would be impossible to judge without this knowledge. Even Buddhists like ourselves, performed unskillful actions while cultivating dana and restraints. To denied the charitable acts (esp. those out of good intentions) of others because of their defilement would be denying them a chance of balancing their bad karma with some good ones. Everyone needs some good karma when stuck in the midst of their misfortune.

Comment: I found this sutta however it does not sound completely on topic:

“Mendicants, even if a monk is of impeccable character, he might be suspected and distrusted as a ‘bad monk’ for five reasons. What five? It’s when a monk frequently collects alms from prostitutes, widows, voluptuous girls, eunuchs, or nuns. Even if a monk is of impeccable character, he might be suspected and distrusted as a ‘bad monk’ for these five reasons.”

AN 5.102

Comment: Agreed. If I recall there was an example where Ven. Anuruddha accepted an invitation from a woman to stayed a night in her house. I think a monastic rule was created as a result.